# Issue with displaying a BitmapSource in Visual Studio 2013 c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, aforge

I am trying to write a piece of code that updates an `Image.Source` with the previous frame from a video capture device.

I am using the `AForge.NET` API's specifically: `Aforge.Video and Aforge.Video.DirectShow`. It all seems to be running smoothly however when I update my `Image.Source` to the current frame the image goes blank.

You will see in my code that I have saved the bitmaps after various conversions, this was to check whether the bitmap still contained the frame. The test were successful i.e. the image saved was of the frame it was not blank. Below is my code for the `newFrameEvent`, if anyone have any ideas I would be really grateful!

The `newframeEvent` argument is a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` object.

```
 private void NewThermalFrameReady(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs e)
 {   
     //Copy frame into tempoary storage. In format Bitmap          
     this.frame = e.Frame; 

     //Save Bitmap frame for test
     this.frame.Save("C:/Users/Shankar/Documents/Visual Studio 
     2013/Projects/Capture_Devices/Capture_Devices/test.jpg");

     //Get BitmapSource from Bitmap and save to double check conversion was sucessful
     this.finalFrame = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromBitmap(frame);
     CreateThumbnail("C:/Users/Shankar/Documents/Visual Studio 
     2013/Projects/Capture_Devices/Capture_Devices/test2.jpg",
     this.finalFrame.Clone());

     try
     {
         this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
         {
             if (finalFrame!=null)
             {                       
                this.frameDisp.Source = this.finalFrame;
             }      
         }));
     }
     catch (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException)
     {

     }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't this always the case, you spend hours on a problem ask the question and then end up solving it! I had to move:

```
this.finalFrame = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromBitMap(frame);
```

into the dispatcher invoke after it worked perfectly! I'll leave the question up here just in case anyone else has this problem...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to show new image on Picture box;

void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {

```
        pictureBoxVideo.BackgroundImage = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    }
```

So may be try using ;

```
      this.frame = e.Frame.Clone(); // in your code
```